# Existence of a sentence $\varphi$ in structures with equivalence realtion

Tags: model-theory

Let $\mathcal{L} = \{\equiv\}$, where $\equiv$ is a binary relation symbol. How can I show that there is no such $\mathcal{L}$-sentence $\varphi$ that is true in every finite $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathcal{M}$ in which $\equiv^{\mathcal{M}}$ is an equivalence relation on $M$ that has equivalence class of at least $|M|/2$ elements and false in other finite $\mathcal{L}$-structures?

I think I have to use ultraproducts here in order to show it, but I don't know how to begin. I'd appreciate any help on this exercise.

Comment: This can probably again be solved in two different ways, using compactness or using ultraproducts. I am reluctant to write down the answer using ultraproducts, because it's very similar to the answer to your previous question and you should try to figure this one out on your own. The point is again to construct two sequences of structures which converge to the same infinite structure (i.e. which have an isomorphic ultraproduct). You could use the same idea with structures of even and odd cardinality. Maybe you want $\varphi$ true in the even structures and false in the odd ones.

Comment: To be more specific, you could start by coming up with structures of cardinality, say, 6 and 7 which are as similar as possible to each other but $\varphi$ holds in the former structure and fails in the latter. There are presumably many ways one could do this, but one of them could strike you as being particularly simple.